# 'No package nginx available' error CentOS 6.5

Tags: linux, nginx, centos, installation, centos6.5

I'm trying to install nginx on CentOS 6.5, then I added these lines on file /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo
[image]

Then install nginx by: 
[image]

And I've got a message error: No package nginx available
How can I fix it? I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem!

Answer (score 42):

nginx is not a part of base CentOS repository.

But you can install EPEL repositiry to get nginx:

> yum install epel-release

and then

> yum install nginx

Comment: No package epel-release available.

Comment: @Jyothu After installing epel-release manually, it works!
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/installing-rhel-epel-repo-on-centos-redhat-7-x/

Answer (score 15):

This should work well for oraclelinux7

```
rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
yum -y install nginx
```

Dockerfile to install nginx on oraclelinux:

```
FROM oraclelinux:7-slim
RUN rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
RUN yum -y install nginx && yum clean all && rm -rf /var/cache/yum
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Answer (score 11):

What worked for me (CentOS 7.1) was removing epel first:

```
yum remove epel-release
yum install epel-release
yum update
yum install nginx
```

Comment: This works for me on CentOS release 6.10 (Final)

Answer (score 10):

Your repo url is having an error.
It is necessary to manually replace $releasever with either "5" (for 5.x) or "6" (for 6.x), depending upon your OS version. Similarly you have to edit the $basearch also.
After that do the following command

**yum clean all**

**yum install nginx**

An alternative option is to install the epel repository and install nginx from there.

**yum install epel-release**

**yum clean all**

**yum install nginx**

Answer (score 1):

Install `nginx` first! Run the following commands to first add the EPEL repository (Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux) and then install nginx.

```
yum install epel-release
yum install nginx
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable plugins for yum:

```
vim /etc/yum.conf
```

set plugins=0, and re-install epel-release:

```
yum remove epel-release
yum install epel-release
yum install nginx
```

this works for me, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Check if it is excluded from the yum source:

1. Use  `vi /etc/yum.conf`
2. Check the `exclude` option

Answer (score 0):

Although the otherwise-posted advice regarding manually setting the `$releasever` and `$basearch` values in the repo file will not hurt per se (at least while you stick to the software release referred to by the values you set), it is not strictly necessary.

I also have the exact contents you have posted, in a file named `/etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo` which functions correctly without having set the above values explicitly.

My advice would be to perform a `yum update`prior to attempting to install (as it's possible that when you tried to install, yum had not queried all of the repo URLs from the files in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` for the latest versions of their databases). Also make absolutely sure that your created file ends in `.repo` as otherwise it will be ignored by yum.

Failing that, check the SElinux security contexts on the files in that directory - or just go ahead and manually restore them by running  `restorecon -Rv '/etc/yum.repos.d'` and check the file permissions on the manually created repo file(s), which should be owned by root:root and have show 644 as file permissions. To manually amend these, run `chmod 644 /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo`and `chown root:root /etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo`

I hope that some part of the above resolves your issues!

Answer (score 0):

**Check `yum.conf` file and it's `exclude` key**

In addition to all above answers, Make sure `nginx`, `httpd` or any other package you want to install is not in the `exclude` list of `yum.conf` file.

1. Open `yum.conf` file located at `/etc/yum.conf`
2. Check the `exclude` key and remove `nginx*` if it's there
3. Then try to install your package. in this case `nginx`:

   `sudo yum install nginx`

Answer (score 0):

My problem was this line in `/etc/yum.conf` file:

```
exclude=apache* nginx* httpd* mod_* mysql* MySQL* mariadb* da_* *ftpd exim* sendmail* php* bind-chroot* dovecot*
```

I deleted `nginx*` and tried to install nginx:
 `yum install nginx`